# Python, Cv2, numpy to indicate areas in a picture/image

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy

I want to specify certain areas in an image.

To specify 1 area I can do this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

the_picture = cv2.imread("c:\\picture.jpg")

target_area = the_picture[300:360, 130:280]
```

The type of target_area is type 'numpy.ndarray'.

But a list of coordinates is a problem. I am struggling in turning a list of coordinates into the values required.

what I want to do is:

```
the_picture = cv2.imread("c:\\picture.jpg")

list_of_areas = [
[300:360 , 130:280]
[300:360 , 440:540]
[400:460 , 0:130]
[400:460 , 250:400]
[400:460 , 560:740]

For area in list_of_areas:
    the_picture(area)     ### failed
```

Here are the coordinates:

```
        x   y       x1  y1

Area1   130 300     280 360
Area2   440 300     540 360
Area3   0   400     130 460
Area4   250 400     400 460
Area5   560 400     740 460
```

I tried to give a list like below but it doesn’t work. I also tried to make them strings in a list, changed the Square Brackets into Round Brackets neither worked.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What’s the proper way to give the coordinates?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit strange, so it's difficult to work out exactly what you  are asking.   What output do you want, or at least what do you want it do do, exactly?

Comment: @DanielF, thank you for the comment. I want to reach all 5 areas in the picture. (the post was edited)

Comment: `list_of_areas` currently has no commas and an open bracket.  Of course it is a `syntaxError`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, and please correct me if I'm wrong, you could solve your problem by saving and retrieving the area coordinates as individual values, and not as pairs

```
the_picture = cv2.imread("c:\\picture.jpg")

list_of_areas = [
[300, 360, 130, 280],
[300, 360, 440, 540],
[400, 460, 0, 130],
[400, 460 , 250, 400],
[400, 460, 560, 740]]

For y,y1,x,x1 in list_of_areas:
    the_picture[y:y1, x:x1]
```

Comment: fantastic! Never thought of the problem could be solved in such an easy way! Again you made the learning world beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you want. (Added commas and closed your brackets)

```
list_of_areas = [np.index_exp[300:360 , 130:280],
np.index_exp[300:360 , 440:540],
np.index_exp[400:460 , 0:130],
np.index_exp[400:460 , 250:400],
np.index_exp[400:460 , 560:740]]
```

Which gives you a list of tuples of slice objects

```
list_of_areas

[(slice(300, 360, None), slice(130, 280, None)),
 (slice(300, 360, None), slice(440, 540, None)),
 (slice(400, 460, None), slice(0, 130, None)),
 (slice(400, 460, None), slice(250, 400, None)),
 (slice(400, 460, None), slice(560, 740, None))]
```

Now to get your subarrays

```
test = np.random.randint(0,255,(480,960,3)) # random RGB
out = [test[area] for area in list_of_areas]
```

Comment: thank you. Could you please explain the last 2 lines of codes? I don't understand.

Comment: It's just me testing the script.  It extracts the subarrays and puts them in a list

Comment: and how can I apply it to For area in list_of_areas:
    the_picture(area)?

Comment: You're not making any sense again.  Maybe try it in an interpreter and see what you get?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.